# Is there a way to iterate through all possible RequestMappings until the response is "positive"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, httprequest

I have a question regarding the way Spring handles the different request mappings.

Using either one of the following handlers:

1. method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping
2. org.resthub.web.springmvc.router.RouterHandlerMapping

Will only fulfil one request. 
In both cases when the request URL matches a given pattern it goes to the corresponding handler.
The same request will not be matched to any other pattern even if the handler returned an error response.
Using an implementation of OncePerRequestFilter I believe one can redirect the request but only before the request is handled (I think).

So my questions are:
How can I force the DispatherServlet to iterate through all matching request handlers until the request is fulfilled with a "positive" response? Is there an out-of-the-box solution for this?

thanks in advance to anyone that can help